DoE - Factors and factor levels for blending two materials
How do I set up my factor and factor levels in this custom design of experiments? I'm making different aggregate blends for asphalt concrete mixtures.
Aggregate Class A is sourced from 3 quarries: A1, A2, and A3.
Aggregate Class B is sourced from 3 different quarries: B1, B2, and B3.
Class A is blended with Class B at different ratios: 1:0 (all Class A), 2:1, 1:2, and 0:1 (all Class B).
But this creates some weird factor combinations. For example...

A1_B1_1:0 actually means there is no B1 in the mix.
A1_B1_1:0, A1_B2_1:0, A1_B3_1:0 are redundant with eachother.

I could add a factor level for "None" but then it wouldn't be defined at 2:1 or 1:2.
Thanks in advance for the help!
Bryan

In a custom DoE, I have four factors and a linear constraint.
ClassA_Quarry (categorical): A1, A2, A3
ClassB_Quarry (categorical): B1, B2, B3
Perc_ClassA (mixture): 0 to 1
Perc_ClassB (mixture): 0 to 1
Linear constraint: 1Perc_ClassA + 1Perc_ClassB = 1

I'm using Custom DoE in JMP. I'm learning that there's a Mixture variable type that I suspect is part of the answer. I'm trying to figure out how this variable works and how I would apply it to my experiment.
